# Modeling relationships in neo4j when they aren't known initially

Tags: go, neo4j, cypher

I currently have some code that looks through various datasets and models electronic relationships between them.  E.g., JSESSIONID.

I would like to model each user's interactions with an application where they have to submit unique identifiers.  E.g., email address.

In processing logs of the application, I see emailA@host.com use the application with JSESSIONID asdfghjkl.  I then see emailB@host.com also use the applcation with JESSIONID asdfghjkl.  Finally, I see emailB@host.com use JSESSIONID qwertyuiop.

In my go code, it's easy for me to process the logs and write out both emailA@host.com and emailB@host.com as Nodes and then write the JSESSIONID relationship between them.

```
MERGE (a:EMAIL {label:userA@host.com}) MERGE (b:EMAIL {label:userB@host.com}) MERGE (a)-[:asdfghjkl]-(b)
```

However, I don't know the best way to do this at scale. (i.e., Application logs are 1TB in size).  The limitation is memory -- I can't find all email addresses that use asdfghjkl as a SessionIDs without processing all the data, so I can't write out the relationship between them due to memory constraints.

What I would really like to do is to write out something as is follows, but this obviously fails:

```
MERGE (a:EMAIL {label:userA@host.com}) (a)-[:asdfghjkl]
```

Then later:
    MERGE (b:EMAIL {label:userB@host.com}) (b)-[:asdfghjkl]

Can I create these relationships with a query after the fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you should model JSESSIONID as nodes rather than as relationships, as that will allow you to link the JSESSIONID to multiple email addresses, and you can add a unique constraint on the id for fast lookups.

```
MERGE (a:EMAIL {label:userA@host.com}) 
MERGE (b:EMAIL {label:userB@host.com}) 
MERGE (jsid:JSESSIONID {id:'asdfghjkl'})
MERGE (a)-[:jsid]->(jsid)
MERGE (b)-[:jsid]->(jsid)
```

Your queries to find all :EMAIL nodes using a specific JSESSION id should be quite fast:

```
MATCH (email:EMAIL)-[:jsid]->(jsid:JSESSIONID {id:'asdfghjkl'})
RETURN email
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you're right and I was leaning that way already.  Because my charts can get rather large, I was hoping to simplify it (at least for viewing graphically).  Given your suggested data model, Is there any way to query where I would get JSESSION id as a relation and not a node? I.e., (a)-[:jsid]-(b) instead of (a)--(jsid)--(b)?

Comment: I don't think so. Especially because relationships require two nodes, dangling relationships aren't allowed in Neo4j, so you wouldn't be able to save this info if only one node is using the session id. Also, you'd need to figure out how this will scale with multiple email nodes using the same id. If there are 5 of them, how do you model this? Interconnect all 5 nodes to each other? That doesn't seem efficient. You'd need to probably create some relationship chain. You also wouldn't be able to do fast lookups by session id, at least not with schema indexes. Legacy indexes might work though.